# What to do when looping repeats in 2 different areas

Tags: javascript, html

The code gets the values of the `input` and sends it to the `textarea`, but when you add more than one `title` the values are repeated in the result of the `titles`, for example, the `DESCRIPTIONS` of `title 1` are the same as in `title 2`, why does this happen? and how to make it work without changing the purpose?

> Run the code in [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/markvaaz/pen/pZXLaJ) or [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/markvaaz/ns0dk3Lr/1/)

---

**This is what happens:**
[image: wrong]
**This is what should happen:**
[image: right]

```js
function result() {
  var inp2 = document.getElementsByName("inp2");
  var titu = document.getElementsByName("titu");
  var res = document.getElementById("result");
  res.value = "";
  
if (titu[0]) {
  for (var k = 0; k < titu.length; k++) {
    if (titu[k].value.trim() != '') {
      res.value += `<div>
<span>${titu[k].value.trim()}</span>
</div>
<ul>\n`;
      for (var j = 0; j < inp2.length; j++) {
        if (inp2[j].value.trim() != '') {
          res.value += `<li>${inp2[j].value.trim()}</li>\n`;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}else {
  console.log("test")
  res.value += `<ul>\n`;
    for (var l = 0; l < inp2.length; l++) {
      if (inp2[l].value.trim() != '') {
        res.value += `<li>${inp2[l].value.trim()}</li>\n`;
      }
    }
 }
};

// -----------------------------------------
if (document.getElementById("add2")) {
let cont2 = 1;
document.getElementById("add2").onclick = function clone2() {
  let container2 = document.getElementById("output2");  
  let tempLinha2 = document.querySelector('#template2'); 
  let clone2 = document.importNode(tempLinha2.content, true); 
  
  const label2 = clone2.querySelector("label");
  label2.htmlFor = cont2;
  clone2.querySelector("input").className = cont2;
  
  container2.appendChild(clone2);
  cont2++;
};
document.getElementById("del2").onclick = function del2() {
    document.querySelector('#output2 #linha2:last-child').remove();
};
}
// ---------------------------------------
if (document.getElementById("addtit")) {
let cont3 = 1;
document.getElementById("addtit").onclick = function clone3() {
  let container3 = document.getElementById("output2");  
  let tempLinha3 = document.querySelector('#template3');
  let clone3 = document.importNode(tempLinha3.content, true); 
  
  const label3 = clone3.querySelector("label");
  label3.htmlFor = cont3;
  clone3.querySelector("input").className = cont3;
  
  container3.appendChild(clone3);
  cont3++;
  document.getElementById('add2').id = 'add3';
  document.getElementById('del2').id = 'del3';
};
document.getElementById("deltit").onclick = function deltit() {
    document.querySelector('#output2 #alg:last-child').remove();
    document.getElementById('add3').id = 'add2';
    document.getElementById('del3').id = 'del2';
};
}
// -----------------------------------------
if (document.getElementById("add3")) {
let cont4 = 1;
document.getElementById("add3").onclick = function clone4() {
  let container4 = document.getElementById("output3");  
  let tempLinha4 = document.querySelector('#template2');
  let clone4 = document.importNode(tempLinha4.content, true); 
  
  const label4 = clone4.querySelector("label");
  label4.htmlFor = cont4;
  clone4.querySelector("input").className = cont4;
  
  container4.appendChild(clone4);
  cont4++;
};
document.getElementById("del3").onclick = function del4() {
  document.querySelector('#output3 #linha2:last-child').remove();
};
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<button id="addtit">+ TITLE</button>
<button id="deltit">- TITLE</button>
<button id="add2">+ DESCRIPTION</button>
<button id="del2">- DESCRIPTION</button>
<div id="output2"></div>
<div class='botoes'>
<button onclick="result()" id='done'>DONE</button>
</div>
<div class="header"><span class="title">RESULT</span>
</div>
<div class="linha"><textarea id="result"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
  

<!-- template 2 -->
<template id="template2">
<div class="linha" id="linha2"><div class="coluna1"><label for="0">DESCRIPTION:</label></div><div class="coluna2"><input name="inp2" class="0" type="text"/></div>
</div>
</template>
<!-- template 3 -->
<template id="template3">
<div id="alg">
<div class="linha"><div class="coluna1"><label for="0">TITLE:</label></div><div class="coluna2"><input name="titu" class="0" type="text"/></div>
</div>
<div class="linha" id="linha3"><div class="coluna1"><label for="0">DESCRIPTION:</label></div><div class="coluna2"><input name="inp2" class="0" type="text"/></div>
</div>
<div id="output3"></div>
</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. it's because this part of code in function result:

```
if (titu[0]) {
  for (var k = 0; k < titu.length; k++) {
    if (titu[k].value.trim() != '') {
      res.value += `<div>
        <span>${titu[k].value.trim()}</span>
        </div>
        <ul>\n`;
      for (var j = 0; j < inp2.length; j++) {
        if (inp2[j].value.trim() != '') {
         res.value += `<li>${inp2[j].value.trim()}</li>\n`;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

your titles have the same names : 'titu' , and your descriptions have same names : 'inp2',
 and you have two nested loops, for each title, loop on description, and it results as you see.
it's better to change your code and make different names and ids
by the way. if you persist to do not change your code, you should use one loop for both of them, like this code

```
if (titu[0]) {
  for (var k = 0; k < titu.length; k++) {
    if (titu[k].value.trim() != '') {
      res.value += `<div>
        <span>${titu[k].value.trim()}</span>
        </div>
        <ul>\n`;
        if (inp2[k].value.trim() != '') {
         res.value += `<li>${inp2[k].value.trim()}</li>\n`;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

for the case of more description for each title, you have to change the code of onClick methods of Title+ and Description+, the added title and all of its description must have same parent, and after doing that, it's possible to solve the problem like this . (assuming the parent that I already have said has class name 'parent')

```
function result() {
    var parents = document.querySelectorAll(".parent")
    parents.forEach(function(parent){
       var title = parent.querySelector("titu");
       var descriptions = parent.querySelectorAll("inp2");
       var res = document.getElementById("result");
       if (title.value.trim() != '') {
           res.value += `<div>
           <span>${title.value.trim()}</span>
           </div>
           <ul>\n`;
       }
       descriptions.forEach(function(inp2){
          if (inp2.value.trim() != '') {
             res.value += `<li>${inp2.value.trim()}</li>\n`;
          }
       });
    }); 
}
```

notice that this code could work after modifying Title+ and Description+ events and add same parent with class name parent to title and descriptions inputs

Comment: only works if it is only 1 description, if you add 2 or more, only the first description is added

Comment: yep, it's because all descriptions have same name, and it's not easy to distinguish them. changing the code and create a clean and well formed code is strongly reccommended

Comment: I did not understand the update, could you show me how it works? I started learning javascript recently, so I'm having trouble understanding

Comment: in each iteration of foreach loop, it works on children of a parent node.